# render data via PDO::FETCH_FUNC vs loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been using 2 methods to render data.

The first one:

```
function name($id,$name){
    return '<div id="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</div>';
}
echo implode($pdo->query("SELECT id,name FROM user")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC,'name'));
```

The second one:

```
$users = $pdo->query("SELECT id,name FROM user")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($users as $user){
    echo name($user->id,$user->name);
}
```

I don't really understand how `PDO::FETCH_FUNC` works. I already tried to figure it out. However, this is not so well-documented.

Could anybody please explain this fetch mode? And also, which one performs better? Thank you.

Comment: Example #5 at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php shows how `PDO::FETCH_FUNC` works.

Comment: It looks to me like you figured it out, and your example should work. Note that it's frowned upon to call `implode()` without the separator argument.

Answer (score 2):

**Both** methods are wrong and you have to learn how to use templates and how to separate business logic from presentation logic.

```
$users = $pdo->query("SELECT id,name FROM user")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
tpl::assign('users', $users);
```

is ALL the code for the business logic part.

then in template

```
<?php foreach $users as $row): ?>
    <div id="<?=$row->id?>"><?=$row->name?></div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Frankly, your business logic should contain not a trace of HTML while presentation logic should contain not a single database call.

Comment: Your advise is really new to me. Could you please explain why I should separate these 2 logics. I just think that my code could be shorter if I render data within few lines. Thank you.

Comment: Now now, that was just one example of how `FETCH_FUNC` can be used; you could easily modify some data in the function: `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, function ($row) { $row['title'] = (($row['accessLevel'] == 100) ? getTranslation('Admin') : getTranslation('Normal user')); unset($row['accessLevel']); return $row; });`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name FROM user');
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, array('Foo', 'name'));

Class Foo {
    public static function name($id, $name) { 
        return '<div id="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</div>';
    }
}
```

So basically `FETCH_FUNC` mode fetches records to user defined function. This is useful because you can manipulate the result.

Use static method if you are not passing in an object of the class. You can just pass in an object and not use static method just the way @Barmar noted in comments.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be a static function to call it like that?

Comment: @Barmar I dont think so. Example that you gave from `php.net` does not use static function

Comment: But it's not a class method, either. If a class method isn't static, you need to provide an object to call it on.

Comment: `$foo = new Foo; ... fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, array($foo, 'fooBar'));`